# DRF: How can I show all fields of a m2m field instead of just the name

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm building a simple Lead Generator using Django Rest Framework.
I'm trying to show a list of "assigned facilities" inside a lead using django's many to many fields. But all it will show inside the API is the id of each of the facilities associated to the many to many field. How do I access more than just the name using DRF? I basically need to show the name, a description and a picture of the facility from each facility record.

serializers.py

```
class LeadUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = (
            "id",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "PrimaryAddress",
            "assigned_facilities",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("id", "is_owner")

    def get_is_owner(self, obj):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        return obj.agent == user
```

models.py

```
class Facility(models.Model):
    UUID = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=False)
    mainimage = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    FacilityDescription = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name

class Lead(models.Model):
    assigned_facilities = models.ManyToManyField(Facility,  related_name='assigned_facilities')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can like below:

```
class FacilitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            "id",
            "Name",
            "mainimage",
            "FacilityDescription",
        )


class LeadUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    assigned_facilities = FacilitySerializer(many=True)
    is_owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = (
            "id",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "PrimaryAddress",
            "assigned_facilities",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("id", "is_owner")

    def get_is_owner(self, obj):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        return obj.agent == user
```